# Python: exec statement and unexpected garbage collector behavior

Tags: python, garbage-collection, exec

I found a problem with `exec` (It happened in a system that has to be extensible with user written scripts). I could reduce the problem itself to this code:

```
def fn():
    context = {}
    exec '''
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buf = '1'*1024*1024*200
x = test()''' in context

fn()
```

I expected that memory should be freed by the garbage collector after the call of function `fn`. However, the Python process still consumes the additional 200MB of memory and I have absolutely no clue what is happening here and how to release the allocated memory manually.

I suspect that defining a class inside `exec` is not a very bright idea, but, first of all, I want to understand what is going wrong in the example above.

It looks like wrapping class instance creation in another function solves the problem but what is the difference?

```
def fn():
    context = {}
    exec '''
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buf = '1'*1024*1024*200
def f1(): x = test()
f1()
    ''' in context
fn()
```

This is my Python interpreter version:

```
$ python
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Sep 16 2010, 18:02:00) 
[GCC 4.5.1 20100907 (Red Hat 4.5.1-3)] on linux2
```

Comment: Does doing the same thing in your code (without going through a string and `exec`) give the same results?

Comment: `gc.collect()` seems to solve it. There must be a cyclic loop somewhere. Guessing wildly, x has a reference to its class, the class probably has a reference to the namespace its defined in, and that in turn has a reference back to x.

Comment: Same thing in my code without exec goes well, and garbage collector works as expected.

Comment: Try upgrading to 2.7.1? Maybe that solves it.

Comment: This is more about understanding deeper what is going on to be aware of what worse could happen. 
The workaround I posted solved this particular issue in the example and in my code.
No success with 2.7.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that you're seeing it take up 200Mb of memory for longer than you expect is because you have a reference cycle: `context` is a dict referencing both `x` and `test`. `x` references an instance of `test`, which references `test`. `test` has a dict of attributes, `test.__dict__`, which contains the `__init__` function for the class. The `__init__` function in turn references the globals that it was defined with -- which is the dict you passed to `exec`, `context`.

Python will break these reference cycles for you (since nothing involved has a `__del__` method) but it requires `gc.collect()` to run. `gc.collect()` will run automatically every N allocations (determined by `gc.set_threshold()`) so the "leak" will go away at some point, but if you want it to go away immediately you can run `gc.collect()` yourself, or break the reference cycle yourself before exiting the function. You can easily do the latter by calling `context.clear()` -- but you should realize that that affects all instances of the class you created in it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem has to do with `exec` - the garbage collector just isn't activating. If you extract the `exec`'d code out into the main application, both ways give the same behavior as with `exec`:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buf = '1'*1024*1024*200
x = test()

# Consumes 200MB

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buf = '1'*1024*1024*200
def f1(): x = test()
f1()

# Memory get collected correctly
```

The differences between the two methods is that, in the second one, the local scope changes when `f1()` is called, and I think that the garbage collector fires up when `x` goes out of scope as the function returns control back to the main script. If the scope doesn't change, then the garbage collector waits [until the difference between the number of allocations and the number of deallocations exceeds its threshold](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.set_threshold) (on my machine, the threshold is 700 by default- running Python 2.7).

We can figure out a little of what's going on:

```
import sys
import gc

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buf = '1'*1024*1024*200
x = test()

print gc.get_count()
# Prints (168, 8, 0)
```

So, we see that the garbage collector fires up numerous times, but for some reason doesn't collect `x`. If you test with the other version:

```
import sys
import gc

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buf = '1'*1024*1024*200
def f1(): x = test()
f1()

print gc.get_count()
# Prints (172, 8, 0)
```

In this case, we know that it does manage to collect `x`. So, it seems that when `x` is declared in the global scope, it retain some cyclic reference to itself that prevents it from being collected. We can always use `del x` to manually force the collection, but of course that isn't ideal. If using `gc.get_referrers(x)`, we'll be able to see what objects still refer to `x`, and maybe that will give a clue on how to stop that from happening.

I know that I didn't really solve the issue, but hopefully this helped you in the right direction. I'll keep this issue in mind, in case I find something later.

Comment: The cyclic garbage collector doesn't "fire up" to destroy local variables -- it isn't involved in local variables as such at all. Python uses reference counting, and destroying local variables is as simple as a decref operation. The `gc` module's collector is a separate thing, and really only fires up when the allocation threshold is hit (or when you call it manually, of course.)

Comment: @Thomas: Oh, I see. Calling `gc.collect()` manually doesn't destroy `x` if it isn't evaluated within `exec`, however. Why would that be?

Comment: I'm not sure which case you're describing here. The cyclic-gc collector will only collect *unreachable*, collectable reference cycles. References to objects. `x` is a local variable -- it's a name, not an object. It holds a reference. The thing `x` *refers to* can be unreachable, but only by `x` no longer existing. Or the thing `x` refers to can be part of an unreachable reference cycle, but only if the frame that contains `x` is also part of that unreachable reference cycle.

Comment: @Thomas: I'm referring to the line `x = test()`. After that call, `x` is never referred to again. But it doesn't get destroyed, so does that mean that something is still referencing it? Is it referencing itself?

Comment: The `x` local variable refers to it. If you mean "like in the original code", the local namespace is the global namespace -- the `context` dict -- and it's part of the reference cycle. It won't go away until `context['x']` is deleted somehow, or `context` itself is destroyed (which requires breaking the reference cycle.)